# Invalid value for schema Array path

Tags: mongoose, schema

I am trying to build comment model contains: Reply and CommentThread. CommentThread contains Reply, and Reply can recurse itself.

/models/comment.js :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var replySchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  body: String,
  replies: [replySchema]
}, {_id: true});

var commentThreadSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  replies: [replySchema]
});

var Reply = mongoose.model('Reply', replySchema);
var CommentThread = mongoose.model('CommentThread', commentThreadSchema);

module.exports = {
    Reply: Reply,
    CommentThread: CommentThread
};
```

My error message is : Invalid value for schema Array path 'replies'. Can't replySchema use itself as value type ? Or some other reasons?

```
c:\Users\jacki_000\projects\invictusblog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:297

      throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema Array path `'+ prefix + ke
            ^
TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `replies`
    at Schema.add (c:\Users\jacki_000\projects\invictusblog\node_modules\mongoos
e\lib\schema.js:297:13)
    at new Schema (c:\Users\jacki_000\projects\invictusblog\node_modules\mongoos
e\lib\schema.js:87:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\jacki_000\projects\invictusblog\models\comme
nt.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\jacki_000\projects\invictusblog\services\com
ment-service.js:1:83)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/6134527/

see the example above,  you need to do something like

```
var replySchema = new Schema();
replyschema.add({
  username: String,
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  body: String,
  replies: [replySchema]
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is it because before using replySchema, it should be defined?

Comment: Thanks, Had the same issue when migrating from an older version of mongoose. Issue was how the schema was being defined. The `.add` worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

run

> npm install mongoose@3.8.5

for a quick fix